# htacces not redirecting properly

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with , htaccess 301 redirection, I try to redirect subpage ?id=22 to music-band.
This is what I try:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond ^http://www.mywebsite.pl/?id=22
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.pl/music-band/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What Im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?id=22($|&|\ )
RewriteRUle ^ /music-band/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^music-band/?$ /?id=22 [L]
```